# Does this theorem on tangential quadrilateral have a name?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry

> > Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral, $P$ be a point in the plane let $E$, $F$ be the projections of the incenters of  triangles $\triangle CPB$, $\triangle BPA$ onto $PB$ respectively; Let $G$, $H$ be the projections of the incenters of triangles $\triangle APD$, $\triangle DPC$ onto $PD$ respectively. *Then $ABCD$ is a tangential quadrilateral if only if with **every** arbitrary point P in the plane $EF=GH$.*

Following picture: $ABCD$ be a tangential quadrilateral if only if with $P$ be **every** arbitrary point in the plane then two red segment lengths are equal

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of similar facts, all proved by mere computation in lengths of tangents. I doubt that many of them have - or deserve - names.